# Where did the Filter Friends lists go from the Requests dialog?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

So the old requests dialog had a dropdown for "Filter Friends" which allowed a user to select from their own custom friends lists.

But the new Requests 2.0 only allows us to select either Installed or Uninstalled users or create our own set of filters. Is there a way to enable the old filters? Because the only alternative I know is requesting the user to give our app read_friendslists permission and then querying for those lists.

[image: Dialog screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The requests dialog has the ability to allow the creator to pass in the filter lists you want to show. (See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)  You will need to know what their filter lists are to be able to do so.

Check out http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/.  I've found some good information by reading thru their various examples.  Valuable information that is not disclosed on the main documentation pages.  This is where I came across the filter selection for the dialog.

> Additionally, an application can suggest custom filters as
>   dictionaries with a name key and a user_ids key, which respectively
>   have values that are a string and a list of user ids. name is the name
>   of the custom filter that will show in the selector. user_ids is the
>   list of friends to include, in the order they are to appear.
>
> Example #1
>
> [{name: 'Neighbors', user_ids: [1, 2, 3]}, {name: 'Other Set',
>   user_ids: [4,5,6]}]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately going that route looks not possible for what I want. I just tried and with only 9 friend lists and under 300 friends, I get the following error. :( I was hoping for more of a flag that said "Show Friend Filters".


API Error Code: 105
API Error Description: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum for this operation
Error Message: param filters has too many elements.

Comment: Yeah, I know, programming can be a pain, but that's why we're in such high demand currently and get paid well.  Not many people can do what we do.  Sometimes life is fully of compromises...and it looks like you've got a compromise coming up.